# Lighthouse inconsistent, how should we proceed?

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

we try to optimize our page and use Lighthouse and pagespeed insights. We removed most external scripts like advertizing. But still the lighthouse results differ at any call up to 15 points in mobile score. I learned that the reason could be local network or hardware? But now it is very difficult to optimize or to do A/B test for speed optimization. How do you solve this? Should I do maybe 20 tests with the same setup and build the average score (e.g. for large contenful paint)? This is a lot of work ....Thanks... Michael

Comment: lighthouse shows you exactly where the problems at. could you show us an lighthouse test result?

Comment: run page speed insights if you believe the inconsistencies are local. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/. If you still see wild fluctuations then the problem likely lies with the site not with any local network or hardware as their servers do the testing. Lighthouse powers Page Speed Insights so other than server location etc. you are comparing like for like.

Comment: Same here, running from 70 to 92

Comment: See here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/5064